Can we deploy react frontend and springboot backend to the one single azure WebApp?
I want to deploy react frontend and springboot backend to the azure webApp.
As I don't want to create two separate webApp for the frontend and backend. Is there any ways one creating one webApp can help me here.

You can try to use a Static Web App: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-react?pivots=github
where you can deploy a SPA with Angular, react and so on.
It has an option to use an azure function as backend.
Or use SWA with Azure Spring Apps as backend:


No I want to go with Web App only earlier I had this WebApp with azure functions.
Can it is possible with only web app both the things frontend and backend

No, not posible. You can choose Node as runtime stack to run both front and backend but since you are using spring you need to split.

with the help of docker can we do so..???

Yes, but it has no sense. You need an ACR, web hooks to monitor. Containers normally are placed in AKS, ACA or ACI inside Azure. Also by design you should split front and back.

can't we do monolithic deployment. Where we do  both frontend and backend are packaged and deployed together as a single unit.
Here we deploy java jar.

Not recommended but you can go with docker-compose with one image and everything inside.
